# How do I get gedit to open VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

I've downloaded VirtualBox and am receiving this message:

```
Could not open the file /home/mike/Downloads/vir...16-105871-Linux_amd64.run.

gedit has not been able to detect the character encoding. Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file. Select a character encoding from the menu and try again.
```

There are 2 options to select for Character Encoding:

- Current Locale (UTF-8)
- Western (ISO-8859-15)

Both are not detected. I have tried to run the file and initially change file properties to allow execution from cmd:

```
chmod +x filename
```

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit. Do I need gedit here at all?

Comment: Why would you need `gedit`? How exactly did you run it? You should open a terminal and either run it with its full path (`/home/mike/Downloads/vir...16-105871-Linux_amd64.run`) or `cd` to where it is and run it with `./vir...16-105871-Linux_amd64.run`. Btw why don't you install virtualbox with your distro's package manager? Using the "official installer" is often a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here?
You have a executable file for VirtualBox. 
Why is gedit and Vagrant involved?

All you can really do with the .run file is to run it.

Open a terminal and type:

```
./VirtualBox-5.0.16-105871-Linux_amd64.run
```

Answer (score -1):

@Tom Yan Thanks, but for some reason, I can't comment on here. I have tried both running it in it's full path and using Package Manager located in Administration. My issue is that I installed Vagrant and when I type:

```
vagrant up
```

I get the following message:

```
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as "providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMWare, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which is available for free on all major platforms.
```

I tried:

```
vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER
```

I receive the message:

```
The provider 'PROVIDER' could not be found, but was requested to back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

Comment: You should merge your two accounts together.